# Recursive function not returning the correct value

Tags: python

I had a written a recursive function which checks for a value in list of lists and stores the indexes now once i'm getting the required value i used return statement to exit from the function, even though it exits from child function it's not exiting from the parent function.Is there anything which Im missing which is limiting to exit the function completely once it finds the value.

```
new_index=[]
def check_with_list(dd,check_value):
    global  new_index

    for index,h in enumerate(dd):
        if isinstance(h, list):
            new_index.append(index)
            check_with_list(h,check_value)
        elif h==check_value:
            new_index.append(index)
            import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
            return new_index
    else:
        new_index=[]



dd=['gcc','fcc',['scc','jhh'],['www','rrr','rrr']]
dd=check_with_list(dd,'rrr')

print dd
```

Answer (score 0):

When calling `check_with_list` on sublists, you don't return the result.

```
def check_with_list(dd, check_value):
    for index,h in enumerate(dd):
        if isinstance(h, list):
            result = check_with_list(h,check_value)
            if result is not None:
                return (index,) + result 
        elif h == check_value:
            return (index,)
    # value not found
    return None


dd=['gcc','fcc',['scc','jhh'],['www','rrr','rrr']]
dd=check_with_list(dd,'rrr')

print dd
```

Comment: Can you please look into the current issue which im in, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51946790/recursive-function-on-sublist-returning-none?noredirect=1#comment90844164_51946790